# 32 плоскогубц(ев) - как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, количественно-именное-сочетание

Возникла трудность со склонением по падежам слова "плоскогубцы". Фраза такая: "Магазин продал за сутки 32 плоскогуб(цев)".
Не знаю, как тут образовать форму родительного падежа. Тридцать два плоскогубца?))) В принципе, можно сказать "двое плоскогубцев", но "тридцать двое" уже не скажешь. Единственная версия, которую могу предложить со своей стороны "32 пары плоскогубцев", но это может ввести в заблуждение, и подумают, что речь идет о 64 предметах.
Помогите, пожалуйста, употребить правильную форму.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ

Магазин продал за сутки  плоскогубцы в количестве 32 штук.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Числительные,  употребляемыми только во множественном числе (рluralia tantum), имеют особые правила сочетаемости с числительными: одни ножницы, двое ножниц/двумя ножницами, пять ножниц/пятью ножницами. Собирательные числительные двое/трое/четверо используются вместо количественных числительных два, три, четыре  только в И-В. падеже. В остальных случаях они сочетаются с количественными числительными по общим правилам.

2) А если это составное числительное, в которое входят числительные два, три, четыре?  Тогда задача сложнее. Дело в том, что собирательные числительные никогда не включаются в составные числительные, в этом случае  делается или замена существительного, или переход к косвенным падежам, где можно использовать количественные, а не собирательные числительные, например:

А) Этот рейс продолжался  26 (суток) → Этот рейс продолжался  26 дней – замена слова сутки   словом  день.

Б) Этот рейс продолжался  в течение двадцати шести суток – замена В. п.→ Р. п.

В) В ДЕЛОВОМ СТИЛЕ уместны следующие выражения:  двадцать две штуки ножниц. Например: Приобретены сани в количестве двадцати двух штук.

Comment: Сейчас в деловом стиле очень часто применяют "единицы" вместо штук. Не закреплено нормой? Кажется это связано с тем, что иногда штуки не применимы, напрмер, рогатый скот?